# Floating Elements in Flexed Divs

Tags: html, css

I've a 3 column layout. My issue is that content in the second `<div>` populates from the bottom, as you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6KZ36/3/). I would like to align it's content to the top.

Following is the corresponding html

```
<div class="user-info" style="width: 100%;">
  <div id="image-container">
    <img src="image.jpeg" height="200px" width="200px">
  </div>
  <div id="info">
    <div class="info-item">
        <div class="info-attribute">tullsy</div>
    </div>
    <div class="info-item">
        <div class="info-attribute">tullsy</div>
    </div>
    <div class="info-item">
        <div class="info-attribute">tullsy</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="button-container">
    <input type="button" id="edit_button" value="edit" class="button" onclick="function()">
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

and css

```
#image-container {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100;
}
#info {
 display: inline-block;
}
#button-container {
 display: inline-block;
 float: right;
 padding: 10px;
}
```

I can fix this issue by applying `display: flex;` for the container, however it seems I can't float elements inside a `flex` container.

I've managed to achieve what i want using `<br>`, as you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6KZ36/6/). But i want to achieve the same without using `<br>`s or fixed padding.

Comment: First of all, nothing is clear from that fiddle. all i can see is a broken image and 3 words. Secondly, please avoid using inline styles, which makes your code unreadable and hard to work with - [Why use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS). A cleaned up fiddle or an image of desired output would help.

Comment: sorry about coming back with the same thing but now you're mixing inline styles and css which is even worse, ah never mind. "Style-equiv. to this but without padding with <br>s" - i still didn't get this part. We can't help you without understanding what you're trying to do.. :/

Comment: whoops, i left in the #info inline by accent (i left the container css because the inline is dead simple). What I mean by that is that I want my result to look exactly like the `<br>`d fiddle but without cheating by padding the "tullsy" lines up towards the top of the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood correctly, 
First of all you need to apply a `height` to the container `#info`, (*So you can avoid using `<br>`s to add height*) Otherwise it'll shrink wrap to the height of it's child items.

Then you can apply `vertical-align:top;` for aligning the `inline-block` child items in it to the top without using `<br>`s

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6KZ36/7/)